# Icons inside of buttons getting shifted to the right when max-width threshold comes into play

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Sorry for the verbose title, I didn't really know how else to explain whats happening.  Let this JsFiddle speak for what my problem is: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/305608/

If you notice on the buttons that have had their text truncated the icons seem to have a shift to the right a few pixels. I have no clue what to make of this or why it happens.

Here is the HTML code I'm using to replicate this issue in my project:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content">
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>1
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>234567890
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>3
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>4
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>5
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>6
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>7
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>8
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>9
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>10
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>11
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>12
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>13
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>14
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>15
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>16123412341234
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>17
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>18
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>19
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>20
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>21
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
.content {
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content div {
    width: 95px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;    
}

.content div i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

button {
  max-width: 95px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I am using bootstrap, which I'd assume there is probably something causing this phantom shifting, but I don't have any idea where to start.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply correct this by adjusting `text-align` to `left`. By default it's set to `center` and when the text is tuncated it seems that the space needed for the `...` is less that the omitted words thus everything will be shifted to get centred.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.content {
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content div {
    width: 95px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;    
}

.content div i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

button {
  max-width: 95px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align:left;/*added*/
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content">
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>1
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>234567890
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>3
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>4
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>5
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>6
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>7
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>8
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>9
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>10
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>11
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>12
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>13
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>14
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>15
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>16123412341234
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>17
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>18
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>19
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>20
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>
          <i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg" #icon></i>21
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```